# ngIf container breaks async ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour in Angular2 when I wrap an `ngIf` container around a list created using `ngFor`. It appears as though the view doesn't render items in the observable array the first time they are inserted after the `ngIf` container becomes visible.

Please see the [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/M1CG9VzAxhVxh6hYOazg?p=preview) that demonstrates this unexpected behaviour. I am expecting that the first example would show *banana* at the same time *Loaded* appears.

*Am I doing something stupid or is this a rendering bug?*

---

<kbd>[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/M1CG9VzAxhVxh6hYOazg?p=preview)</kbd>

*app.service.ts*

```
export class AppService {
  private _things = new Subject<Array<any>>();
    public things = this._things.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    var that = this;

    // simulate ajax request
    setTimeout(function() {
      that._things.next([
          {'id': 1, 'text': 'banana'}
        ]);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      that._things.next([
        {'id': 1, 'text': 'banana'},
        {'id': 2, 'text': 'orange'}
      ]);
    }, 6000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      that._things.next([
        {'id': 1, 'text': 'banana'},
        {'id': 2, 'text': 'orange'},
        {'id': 3, 'text': 'apple'}
      ]);
    }, 9000);
  }
}
```

*app.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h4>Does have *ngIf</h4>
    <div *ngIf="hasThings">
      Loaded
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let thing of things | async">
          {{thing.id}}: {{thing.text}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <h4>Doesn't have *ngIf</h4>
    <div>
      Loaded
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let thing of things | async">
          {{thing.id}}: {{thing.text}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NgClass, NgStyle, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  public hasThings = false;

  private _things = new Subject<Array<any>>();
  public things = this._things.asObservable();

  constructor(private _appService: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._appService.things
      .subscribe(things => {
        this.hasThings = things.length > 0;
        this._things.next(things);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your plunk seems to work for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is you are using `Subject` in your Component and `async` pipe in your template. If you change the `Subject` object in your Component to `BehaviorSubject`, you'll get the expected result.

```
private _things = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>();
```

One of the main differences between `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` is `BehaviorSubject` returns you the last value it keeps right when you subscribe to it, when `Subject` does not. In your code, when first `ngIf` condition is satisfied, the DOM is initiated and the first list calls `subscribe`. At that time, `Subject` will not emit anything and you have to wait till the next event to update the list.

Working plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Obso0Odl3PoPw699AQ5W?p=preview

Comment: Yup, here's my plnkr (Forked from his, only edited import line and declaration line): https://plnkr.co/edit/Obso0Odl3PoPw699AQ5W?p=preview

Comment: Ah great, thanks! Initially I thought it wasn't working either as I used the `BehaviorSubject` for the service instead of the component. I suppose it should probably be used for both. Can I suggest you update your answer to remove ambiguity?

Comment: How would we go about turning an existing observable into the behavior subject needed for this?